# How do I send data to specific Socket connections?

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I understood that every client is connected through a socket with a new thread each, but how do I send data to a specific client socket? What should I do to fix this issue? Here is my server's source code:

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {
    public Server() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1124);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        System.out.println("Server is running");

        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            executorService.execute(new ConnectionHandler(s));    
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server();
    }    
}

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {    
    Socket s;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {    
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your inputstream should be of the same socket where you want to send an output?

Comment: actually, how do i differentiate between Socket(Client one) and Socket(Client 2)?...how can i send data to Client one socket when the Client 2 thread is running...

Comment: you should keep track of all your ConnectionHandler's, you need a List of them and simply add a connection to it after accepting it. on that way you can send a message to specific client, but, you should change your ConnectionHandler, because it does not do anything there.

Comment: I answered your query just a moment ago, check it out.

Comment: Reza could you please provide a simple example? i would appreciate.

Comment: You should never use `while(true)` directly, use a boolean variable instead and pass it in the while loop.

Comment: You write to its output stream. Unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: @AkashAgarwal That assertion is entirely opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all the users that are connecting to the server in a linked list and pass that as well to each client connection. That way you can traverse through the linked list to find the connection you want to communicate with and send data to its `outputstream`.

**EDIT** Example-

Code for server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBServer {
    static boolean listening = true;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    static List<ClientThread> users = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    users= new LinkedList();
    int portNumber = 17000;
    System.out.println("Now using port number=" + portNumber);
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (listening) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Number of users connected: " + users.size());
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Someone just joined.");
            ClientThread ct= new ClientThread(clientSocket);
            users.add(ct);
            ct.start();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The server maintains a list of connected users in the `List<ClientThread> users` variable which can be accessed by the client threads.

ClientThread Code:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
private Socket clientSocket = null;
ClientThread(Socket s){
    this.clientSocket= s; 
    //give this thead a unique identifier like a name using this.setName() method
}
void sendMessage(){
    for (ClientThread c : DBServer.users) {
        if(c.getName().equals(/*Name of thread you want to contact*/)){
            //send message here
        }
    }
}
}
```

Set a name of the thread using `this.setName()` method. Should be a unique identifier.
Now you can communicate with the thread you want to using `users` variable and traversing through all of them using `getName()` method.

Comment: could you please provide a simple example...Thankyou.